# Html video streaming size exceeds the file size , how to cache and optimise html video element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video-streaming, html5-video

I am trying to stream a video from a `NodeJS` server and it is working fine. But the problem is with the video size, which is 61MB. As I change my range in the html video element it fetches again, which causes a loop and fetch size will exceed 100 mb if continued. How not to load the video anymore, after the video is fully loaded and keep stream size maximum to video size?

[networks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGqt5.png)

Comment: i suggest you to reduce video size, or host any other video platform or add into iframe or player, it's make more batter experience

Comment: I don't use Node-JS so what does _"trying to stream video from node js server"_ mean exactly? Like **(1)** Do you have videos files online or is NodeJS acting like a localhost server?  **(2)** What is the **src** of the `<video>` tag? Is it a real video file or a script file that gets the video file? **(3)** If you leave out the NodeJS server part, and just play the file in an HTML does it work okay (no reloads when seeking the timeline)?

Answer (score 1):

> but the problem is video size is 61MB

This is not a problem.

> as i change my range in html video element it again fetches which goes in loop and fetch size exceeds 100 mb if continued

The browser is trying to optimize what to fetch, making assumptions about the way a video will be played.  Ideally, it only wants to download the video that's actually used and no additional video.

> how not to load video anymore if the video is fully loaded and keep stream size maximum to video size

You need tighter control over the caching behavior.  Fortunately, you can do this with a [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API).  The Service Worker can be built to intercept requests form the media elements, and cache ranged requests together into a single resource.  If the resource is needed again later, the Service Worker will control fetching it directly from local cache.